# can i weight content-types and manually manage the display?

Tags: nodes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reorder Content Types in (“/node/add”)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26776/reorder-content-types-in-node-add)

Can I weight **content-types** (not nodes created) and manually manage the display?

Presently, i am prepending some content-types with an x so that they float to the bottom of the content-types list.