# Reorder Content Types in ("/node/add")

Tags: 7, nodes

Is there a way to reorder the content types shown on node/add?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yup! Simply edit your "Navigation" menu (at /admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation) and reorder the menu entries under "Add content". Now when you go to /node/add they'll appear in whatever order you set them in your "Navigation" menu. Example screenshot below. On /node/add they will appear as Basic Page, then Article.

[image]

Comment: oh dear how I could miss that. Feeling stupid...

Comment: don't, the only reason I realized you could do that was by answering a different question a few days ago... had you asked this last week I'd have had no idea :)

Comment: Just a complementary question here : the Add content menu is well reordered in the Nav menu but in the top Admin menu, the order is still alphabetical. Any tip to reorder the Add content entries in the admin menu? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to resort to a custom module for this as the alphabetical ordering is hard coded into the page callback function [`node_overview_types()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--content_types.inc/function/node_overview_types/7) (it's actually built up in [`_node_types_build()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/_node_types_build/7) which is called from that function).

Without knowing what you want to sort on it's quite difficult to give a full answer but I'll put the skeleton code in:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // Override the default page callback for the content types page
  $items['admin/structure/types']['page callback'] = 'MYMODULE_node_admin_overview';
}

function MYMODULE_node_admin_overview() {
  // Get the normal page build
  $default_build = node_overview_types();

  // Extract the table rows from the build
  $table_rows = $default_build['#rows'];

  // Perform an operation on these rows to re-order them for your needs
  _some_call_by_reference_sort_function($table_rows);

  // Assign the newly ordered rows back to the page build
  $default_build['#rows'] = $table_rows;

  return $default_build;
}
```

Make sure you keep your callback function in the main module file otherwise you'll have to mess about with overriding the `file` key for the original menu item which is never fun.

You'd have to implement your own administration page if you want to be able to change the ordering through the UI.

Comment: Thanks Clive. I just thought there might be a different way.