# Reorder Content Types in ("/node/add")?

Tags: 8, navigation

In drupal 7 it can be do like this. [7 - Reorder Content Types in ("/node/add") - Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26776/reorder-content-types-in-node-add)

How can I reorder Content Types with Drupal 8?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Drupal 8 doesn't respect the menu structure anymore when displaying the node types. Node types have no weight concept, so there is no direct way to control this.

What you could do is to implement a template/preprocess for node_add_list/node-add-list.html.twig and then reorder the types in code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good solution in contrib (Drupal 7 and modern Drupal) that makes it easy again, providing a separate menu to power a replacement "Add content" page:

https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_add_content

(Glad i found that module as i was about to make the equivalent, since it was my fault it got difficult— i reported [the bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/1009982) that disconnected the menu from the page!)

Another really great Drupal 8 option is the Type Tray module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/type_tray

which vastly enhances the Content Add page.

Answer (score -1):

Install the [Admin Toolbar](https://drupal.org/project/admin_toolbar) module. The *Navigation* menu is combined with the *Administration* menu; you can edit the *Administration* menu and change the order.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: I can't find `Add content` in Administration menu.

Comment: @snize , Go to the menu section and edit the first menu Administration,
All admin menu items are appear in it. then you can reorder it.

Comment: Please install  "Admin Toolbar" (https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_toolbar) module and follow above steps.

Comment: @Karuna Just tried above thing. It just changes the order of menu. But it does not affect the order on /node/add page.